# NullPointerException returned by Query object in DAO using Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, dao

I'm new in spring, I have 3 projects in my eclipse. One JPA.jar, client.jar and a Web.war.
I am going to deploy these on Tomcat 6 so all the dependencies are mainly on the Web.war.
My problem is that I can persist data in the oracle data base but I cannot get(select) the data from the Query object in the DAO :(.

here is my servlet-context

```
</beans:bean>
                        <!-- Oracle Driver -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sapodev.sapo.co.za:1523/P3P"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="pensions"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="pensions"/>

</beans:bean>

<!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->           
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  

    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="frameworkPU"/>  
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="true"/>  
            <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>  --> 
            <beans:property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/> 
        </beans:bean>  
    </beans:property>  
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" /> 
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
</beans:bean>  

<beans:bean id="persistenceAnnotation"    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />  
<beans:bean id="contactService" class="za.co.sapo.service.ContactServiceImpl"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="za.co.sapo.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="za.co.sapo.dao"/>
</beans:beans>
```

Here is the DAO class

```
public List<DevUserTab> findUsers() {
    List<DevUserTab> list = null;

    log.info("DD");
    try{
        TypedQuery<DevUserTab> query = this.entityManagerFactory.createNamedQuery("SELECT d from DevUserTab d", DevUserTab.class);
        list= query.getResultList();
    } catch(Exception e){
        log.info(" EE");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Here is the service class

```
@Autowired
public ContactDAO contactDAO;
public List findUsers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContactDAO contact = new ContactDAO();
    List users = contact.findUsers();
    return users;
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/table")
public ModelAndView getContacts(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Getting the Contacts for us "+ locale.toString());

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/table");
    try{
        List<Contact> objects = ServiceLayerContext.getContext().findContacts();
        mv.addObject("objects", objects );
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: can you provide complete stack trace?

Comment: You're trying to use a named query.

Answer (score 0):

The `createNamedQuery` expects you to be referencing a query you configured in your persistence.xml

When specifying the JPQL directly as you are doing, you need to use the `createQuery` method instead.